# Unidentified function in Cuda documentation

Tags: cuda, gpu

I find a batched function in cuSOLVER documentation. 
http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/index.html#cuds-lt-t-gt-potrfBatched
But this function can not be found in "cusolverDn.h". I think this may be an error.

Answer (score 4):

This function is only available in CUDA 9.1 and beyond.

You can get the latest CUDA installers [here](http://www.nvidia.com/getcuda)